# Looking for a LayoutLM model with max_embeddings of 1024 instead of 512

Tags: bert-language-model

I'm currently trying to use a LayoutLM model in a project.  However, the max embeddings is 512. I'm trying to see if I can find a pretrained model with 1024 max embeddings.  Does anyone know of such a model or if there is a way around it?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want a higher limit - do you have longer documents or are you looking for more accuracy, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Training such a model will be time-consuming but we will consider that.